# Android: Getting CalledFromWrongThreadException even though the Runnable is posted to the view

Tags: android, runnable, android-framework

I'm facing a weird issue. My code has a broadcast-receiver, which does this in its onReceive():

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    view.refreshUI();
}});
```

I'm confused about the reason for this code to present the `android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

I'm already posting the `refreshUI()` call inside `Runnable` onto `view`. So how does it **not** run on the UI-thread?

Another weird observation is that the broadcast-sending service hasn't even sent the broadcast in the case where I see this crash. I know this because there are statements logged to the logcat on both the sender & receiver side. But one of this are present before the crash.

To give some background, the above code is written inside the Android framework, for the keyguard (OR lock-screen). I'm working on Android 4.3 source-code which is customized for our hardware/board.

The above code is present as it is since last 1.5 years. The issue has been seen only twice in the last few months though nothing has been changed here.

I've already gone through [Running on UIThread and posting to view, still get CalledFromWrongThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456529/running-on-uithread-and-posting-to-view-still-get-calledfromwrongthreadexceptio) & other similar questions, but they are mostly dealing with `AsyncTasks`. I do not have any `AsyncTask` in my case.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Use Activity.runOnUIThread(new Runnable...)

Comment: I cannot do that. As I mentioned, my code is in the default Android-keyguard, which is not an Activity. It is a view that is attached on the UI directly through the WindowManager.

Comment: Can you do ((Activity)view.getContext()).runOnUIThread... ?

Comment: @Nanoc It is not an Activity. Typecasting it won't work. The context used is same as the one created by SystemServer process.

Comment: You should have a way to call runOnUIThread, post more of your code please.

Comment: @Nanoc runOnUIThread() method is available only for Activity. I cannot show my code due to the company-policy, but I can point you to the default Andoird file I'm changing. It is here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.3_r1/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/keyguard/KeyguardPINView.java
I have added a refreshUI() method here & a broadcastReceiver that is registered in onFinishInflate(). The remaining is described in my question.

Comment: Try using handler like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860384/android-how-to-runonuithread-in-other-class

Comment: view.post() internally calls the runnable on the Handler. So how is this different? See the code here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.3_r1/core/java/android/view/View.java#10701

Comment: Cant see the call to getMainLooper so i will not bet is the same, can you just try it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use runOnUiThread() when you want to update your UI from a Non-UI Thread. For eg- If you want to update your UI from a background Thread. You can also use Handler for the same thing.

you Should to use this:

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.refreshUI();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Care to elaborate for the op? Direct answers only aren't very good, even if they do answer the question.

Comment: runOnUiThread isn't available outside of Activity. As I mentioned in the question, this code doesn't run in an activity