# Android: CalledFromWrongThreadException from WebView's shouldOverrideUrlLoading

Tags: android, multithreading, sdk, webview

I am developing on a library that is somehow getting a `CalledFromWrongThread` Exception crash on Samsung Galaxy S1 (api v7 - android 2.1). The code is something like this:

```
class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        someListener.addToUiView();
    }
}
```

and of course, the method that is actually throwing the error (which implements a listener callback):

```
View v;
public void addToUiView(){
    v.addView(new TextView(context)); //<-- this line is throwing the error on rare occasions
}
```

I'm skipping some code in between, but i'm not doing anything weird in other places. Also note: this crash only seems to have been happening a very very small % of the time. (not necessarily conclusive, as not everyone reports their data).

has anyone else come across this?? Is WebCore threading messing things up?

Answer (score 2):

Now I haven't actually tested this but I am going to answer to the best of my knowledge.  That said, my instinct is telling me that you are only seeing the error intermittently because web requests from a `WebView` (browser) happen with varying levels of asynchronicity and probably utilize a thread pool to accomplish this.  Basically, sometimes it requests resources in parallel and sometimes it doesn't. Worse yet you might be seeing this error on only a single device because OEMs optimize OS level code (like the `WebView` internals) based on their preferences and opinions (especially Samsung).  Either way the real problem is that you are doing something "UI related" in a place that is definitely not guaranteed to be "UI friendly"... That is, anywhere where you are getting a subsystem callback.

The solution to your problem is much more simpler than the explanation: just use your `context` (that I am assuming is an `Activity`)..

`Activity`s have a built in function called [`runOnUiThread(Runnable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) that will guard the code inside the runnable from running on the wrong thread.  Basically, your problem is really common and android has a built-in solution.  `runOnUiThread` will only add overhead if required, in other words if your thread is the UI thread, it will just run the `Runnable`, if it isn't it uses the correct `Handler` (the one associated with the UI thread) to run the `Runnable`.

Here is what it should look like:

```
View v;
public void addToUiView() {

    final Activity activity = (Activity) context;

    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            v.addView(new TextView(activity));
        }

    });
}
```

i coded that up right inside the SO window so my apologies for any egregious errors, I hope that helps, and let me know if you need more info or of this doesn't solve your problem -ck